# Get Html from some site issue in DOMXPath

Tags: php, html, dom

I have a html page on some site  and it contains the below html in which i want to retrieve the content inside the div.

```
<div class="st-text" id="review-body">

<p>....</p>

<p>............</p>

<p>..........</p>

</div>
```

I have tried the below code

```
$html = new DOMDocument();
@$html->loadHtmlFile('www.somesite.com');
$xpath = new DOMXPath( $html );
$nodelist = $xpath->query( "//div[@id='review-body']/p/" );
echo "<pre>";print_r($nodelist);exit;
```

I am getting the below error

```
DOMXPath::query(): Invalid expression
```

Can anyone please help to to write the correct query in the `$xpath->query()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this expression instead:

```
$nodelist = $xpath->query("//div[@id='review-body']//p");
```

Or if you know that `p` you are looking for are direct descendant of the `#review-body` div, then the expression can be `//div[@id='review-body']/p`.

Comment: Hi thanks for the quick reply i am getting DOMNodeList Object
(
    [length] => 9
) as output with the code you provided. i want the full content of the div how should i proceed now

Comment: If you want content of the div then use `//div[@id='review-body']/text()`.

Comment: Sorry but tried the syntax in your comment and got the same output as before

Comment: You will need to iterate over returned nodes and get text value of each.

Comment: Can you please add some example code in your answer to get and idea

Comment: Just use `foreach` loop with `foreach ($nodelist as $node) { echo $node->nodeValue; }`.

Comment: Thanks it worked now but with //div[@id='review-body']//p and not with text() Thanks a lot :)

Comment: one more thing what if i want to get the html inside p tag currently its returning text only